# Exporting two listboxes on excel file using Openxml

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I have to export two listboxes (with the same size) as two columns of the same excel spreadsheet. For this purpose, I should use OpenXML that has to be integrated into a Savefiledialog, so I provided the following code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel 2010 Workbook (*.xlsx*)|*.xlsx|Excel 2000 Workbook (*.xls*)|*.xls|OpenOffice Spreadsheet (*.ods*)|*.ods|XML Document (*.xml*)|*.xml"
        SaveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = False
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim spreadSheet As SpreadsheetDocument = Nothing
            Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart
            Dim sheets As Sheets
            Dim sheet As Sheet
            spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, False)
            spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart()
            Spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = New Workbook()
            Spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()
            Spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets()
worksheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
        For i = 1 To Form3.Label14.Text - 1
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = New Worksheet(Form3.ListBox1.Items(i))
        Next
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()
        End if 
    End Sub
```

I have two issue: the first is that, as the code shows, I'm not able to fill the second column with the items of ListBox2. The second problem is about an error that Visual Studio shows me:

```
Error   BC30519 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Overloads Sub New(childElements As IEnumerable(Of OpenXmlElement))': Argument matching parameter 'childElements' narrows from 'Object' to 'IEnumerable(Of OpenXmlElement)'.
    'Public Overloads Sub New(ParamArray childElements As OpenXmlElement())': Argument matching parameter 'childElements' narrows from 'Object' to 'OpenXmlElement'.
    'Public Overloads Sub New(outerXml As String)': Argument matching parameter 'outerXml' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'.
```

Hoping OpenXML is being used in the right way, How could I solve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Form3.Label14.Text - 1` The .Text property of a Label is a String. How do you expect to subtract 1 from a String? Turn on Option Strict now and forever.

Comment: Label14.text Is the CInt of a variable prevoiusly defined, it's not a string. Actually option strict is turned on yet.

Comment: A label's .Text property is a String. Period! That line of code would be underscored with a red squiggle if Option Strict was on.

Comment: So, I wrote CInt(Form3.Label14.Text), in order not to have a string in the for loop. Then I went to Debug>Options>Project and Solutions>VB Default and Option Strict is already set on ON. Is that what you meant or is there any other way to enable option strict? Anyway, I've tried to debug again but I'm still getting the same error reported in the question.

Comment: But your code doesn't have CInt() This is a direct copy/paste from your question above `For i = 1 To Form3.Label14.Text - 1` To answer your question... Yes, that will set it on for future projects but check Project Properties -> Compile -> Option Strict drop-down box ON for the current project.

Comment: My fault, I told you badly. I've changed the upper bound of the for loop with CInt(). Btw, I verified the position you told me and Option Script was Off. Now that I've enabled it, I have several errors and I'm trying to solve them. On the other hand, on OpenXML, I'm having back once again the same error of my question. Thinking that I'm not using OpenXML in the right way.